# Playground Xcode swift: WKWebView_scripting[..] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift-playground

I created a new playground to learn using `WKWebView`. I started with the following code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import WebKit

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height:600)
let web = WKWebView(frame: frame)
```

then I get the following apparent error output messages written to the console:

```
2016-05-08 09:31:50.261 WKWebView_scripting[1219:82092] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/folders/3w/jr5wk3ls4rb2l6fvks5mthkm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.WKWebView-scripting-63C77091-F9CA-4CBE-AD9B-376D4857F44B/Library/Caches    /com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.WKWebView-scripting-63C77091-F9CA-4CBE-AD9B-376D4857F44B. Errno:1
2016-05-08 09:31:50.263 WKWebView_scripting[1219:82092] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/folders/3w/jr5wk3ls4rb2l6fvks5mthkm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.WKWebView-scripting-63C77091-F9CA-4CBE-AD9B-376D4857F44B/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.WKWebView-scripting-63C77091-F9CA-4CBE-AD9B-376D4857F44B. Errno:1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong.

This error message means that Playgrounds are sandboxed - WKWebView can't use caching.

But the webview still works.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import WebKit

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height:600)
let web = WKWebView(frame: frame)
let rq = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://apple.com")!)
web.loadRequest(rq)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = web
```